# go get fails for hashicorp/levant

Tags: go, go-get

I inherited a build script that builds a docker image and uses `hashicorp/levant` library to deploy. For a year or so we have been running `go get github.com/jrasell/levant` to grab the `levant` library.   In past few days, the repo URL was merged under Hashicorp's organization and we've changed our script to pull with  `go get github.com/hashicorp/levant`. But either way, we get this multi assign error.  What does this mean, doesn't 'go' just basically pull the git repo?

```
../go/src/github.com/hashicorp/levant/template/render.go:28:11: cannot assign 
*"github.com/hashicorp/nomad/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/nomad/api".Job to job 
(type *"github.com/hashicorp/nomad/api".Job) in multiple assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `go get` works with packages, not repositories.

In addition to pulling them `go get` also compiles and installs them, and here's when your error pops up.

More info here:

https://nanxiao.gitbooks.io/golang-101-hacks/content/posts/go-get-command.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **[Go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)**.

`hashicorp/levant` does have `go.{mod,sum}` files and hence you should forget using the go get way.

It's better to do a clone and follow the go module way i.e.,

```
git clone git@github.com:hashicorp/levant.git
go test ./...
go build ./...
```

The steps with not only just clone your repo but would also bring your dependent packages required for building/ testing the package.

> Note: You should have *Go v1.11+*

Comment: Thanks... But I get a lot of error like this using this method

levant/commands.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/hashicorp/levant/command" in any of:
 /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.14.7/x64/src/github.com/hashicorp/levant/command (from $GOROOT)
 /home/runner/go/src/github.com/hashicorp/levant/command (from $GOPATH)
levant/commands.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/hashicorp/levant/version" in any of:
 /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.14.7/x64/src/github.com/hashicorp/levant/version (from $GOROOT)
 /home/runner/go/src/github.com/hashicorp/levant/version (from $GOPATH)

Comment: Where actually you're cloning this? Either do it outside of `GOPATH` or if you're cloning it inside `GOPATH`, then make sure to have a structure similar to: `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp/levant` and then try `go build ./...`